# Getting products with at least one image

Tags: python, django

My models looks like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(...)
    ...
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='images', blank=True, null=True)
```

I need to alter the following to make it only fetch products with at least one image:

```
products = Product.objects.filter(status='PU').order_by('?')[:4]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
products = Product.objects.filter(status='PU', images__isnull=False).order_by('?')[:4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Annotate, then filter on the annotation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/

```
Product.objects.annotate(image_count=Count('images')).filter(image_count__gt=0)
```

Comment: Not quite, need to change `'productimage'` to match his `related_name`, so `image_count=Count('images')`